# Locating an audio file to play in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm a Swift guy going back to do some Objc work and I'm trying to add a sound to my app, problem is, the `path` is `null` when trying to locate the file

The file is located at `myProj/Resources/Sounds/genericButtonPress.wav`

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myProj/Resources/Sounds/genericButtonPress" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSLog(@"%@", path); // NULL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    [player play];
```

From the docs, it looked like `pathForResource` had to be absolute but I've also tried with just `genericButtonPress` as my string.

Would love some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"genericButtonPress" ofType:@"wav"];` ?

Comment: I did. No luck.

Comment: For your question, you said the `wav` file name is `mysound`. But in your code you are looking for `genericButtonPress`. Are you sure you aren't using the wrong name? Try `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myProj/Resources/Sounds/mysound" ofType:@"wav"];`.

Comment: Sorry, that was an editing error. I updated the original post. The file is called `genericButtonPress.wav`

Comment: Oh ok. Another thing to consider is, are you developing a framework and app in the same project? Because if the file is added to the framework's bundle you need to access the file via the *framework's bundle*. The ObjC syntax should be something like this: `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"YourFrameworkName"];`

Comment: I don't believe I am, no. I just have `@import AVFoundation;` at the top of my file

Comment: I didn't have my audio files in the right target. Answered my own question below. Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is this:

Remember kids, always make sure that your files are assigned to your proper target or things won't show up and won't work. That goes for fonts and audio files especially.

Comment: I gave you exact answer bro.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;
- (IBAction)actionPlayAudio:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)actionPlayAudio:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youraudiofilename" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    [player play];
}
```